# Same variable's markers didn't connected continuously in plotly scatter line graph

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm trying to draw a line graph by plotly_graph_objs and dash.

When I plot data and connect each points based on xaxis which has range 1 to 100, the line doesn't connect the points at once. Which means, the line just connected some values of xaxis, and another line connected the other values.
The connections were not processed in ascending order. The one connected xaxis 1 and 100, another connected 2 to 10 and so on.

I think point should be connected continuously at once in graph, if they were in same condition. But I can't figure it out by myself..
How do I fix it?

What I've already done is:
1. sort the data by xaxis,
2. change xaxis to numeric,

'''

## df

```
'''
class_mid   class_sub   class_ssub  yr  a   b   c   d   e
percentile  .   1   2016    319 315 302 301 313
...
percentile  .   100 2016    332 349 337 389 388
percentile  .   100 2017    345 349 351 408 402
percentile  .   100 2018    357 353 356 419 415
percentile  .   100 2019    365 375 369 451 442
decile      .   1   2016    345 349 351 408 402
...
decile      .   10  2019    378 423 502 403 322

'''
```

'''

## layout explanation

```
'''
id: main_graph: dcc.Graph /
id: var:    dcc.Dropdown -> choice one of [a, b, c, d, e] /
id: yr:     dcc.Rangeslider -> min=1998, max=2020 /
id: class_mid:  dcc.Dropdown -> choice percentile or decile
'''
```

'''

```
import datetime
import math
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table_experiments as dt
import plotly.graph_objs as go

@app.callback(
    Output('main_graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('var', 'value'),
     Input('yr', 'value'),
     Input('class_mid', 'value')])
def update_main_graph(var, yr_slider, class_mid):

    traces=[]
    for i in range(int(yr_slider[0]), int(yr_slider[1])):
        if var == 'percentile':
            g = df[[var, 'class_mid', 'class_ssub', 'yr']]
            g = g[g['class_mid'].isin(['percentile'])]
            g['class_ssub'] = pd.to_numeric(g['class_ssub'])
            g = g.sort_values(['yr', 'class_ssub'])
            traces.append(
                go.Scatter(
                    x=g[g['class_mid'] == class_mid]['class_ssub'].unique(),
                    y=g[g['yr'] == i][var],
                    mode='lines+markers',
                )
            )

    figure = go.Figure(data = traces)

    return figure
```

I expect the one line graph when I choose a year on Rangeslider,
but the actual is two or more lines.
[image]